# Prove or Disprove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{(x^n+y^n+1)^n}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I was experimenting with the value some basic double integral(Polar) by changing powers of $x$ and $y$, limits In the end I observed that as we increase $n$ the value of the following limit approaches 1.

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{(x^n+y^n+1)^n}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=1$$

I don't know where to start evaluating the limit. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Use DCT. Consider $x<1$ and $x>1$. Similarly, $y<1$ and $y>1$. The proof is quite elementary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hi, do you mean analyzing four different parts individually?

Comment: Yes, that is right.